# Jasper Reports Server - Error filling report

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

My workaround is:

- *Windows 7*
- *Jasper Reports Server 4.7.0*

I have installed the bundled version on my workstation and chose to install the *iReport* package too.  Install would not proceed with default path *`c:\program files\<JasperReport>`* known issue with *Win 7*.  Installed successfully in *`c:\<JasperReport>`*.

I have a configured *DSN datasource* to my *as400* data and also use ***dbVisualizer*** that uses *JDBC to ODBC bridge* with this datasource.  I used the same datasource in JR and the test connection succeeds.  When I build a report in *iReport* I can preview my data fine.  I then choose to add the report to the Repository Nav, stepping through the wizard.  When I go to the web browser to view the report in *JasperReport Server* I get the error:

```
  The Server has encountered an error. Please excuse the inconvenience.  
ERROR Message  com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSException: Error filling report.
Followed with some Error Traces.
```

I have also tried to manually add the datasource to the *JRS* repository, test the connection <passed> and then in *iReport*, add the report using the Repository datasource but same error.

Comment: Did you check the stacktrace?

Comment: Referring to the trace entries?  No, sorry they weren't making much sense to me.  There were actually 3 sections of errors returned.

The server has encountered an error. Please excuse the inconvenience.
 
Error Message
com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSException: Error filling report
 
Error Message
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error preparing statement for executing the report query : SELECT "CFMAST"."CFNA1", 
 
Error Message
java.sql.SQLException: [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS] - Error message text unavailable. Message can not be translated successfully.